# why does this program crash when I enter big numbers like 10 5000000?

Tags: c++, function, crash

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
bool is_prime(int num , int cnt = -1){
    if(cnt == -1)
        cnt = num-1;

    if(num <= 1)
        return false;

    if(cnt == 1)
        return true;

    if(num % cnt == 0)
        return false;

    return is_prime(num , cnt-1);

}

int count_primes(int start , int end){
    if(start>end)
        return 0;
    if(is_prime(start))
        return 1 + count_primes(start+1 , end);
    else
    return 0 + count_primes(start+1 , end);
}
int main()
{
    cout<<count_primes(10 , 200);

    return 0;
}
```

why does this program crash when I pass to the function
count_primes arguments like 10 and 5000000.

when I pass arguments like 10 and 50 it works well.

Comment: Recursion requires system resources in order to function (each call needs it's own space in memory).  Once you get enough recursive calls, you'll run out of that memory.

Comment: Your `is_prime` recurses O(n) times, most of them uselessly.  Any factor greater than sqrt(N) must be paired with one less than sqrt(N).  Incorporating that rule will not only speed things up significantly, it will dramatically reduce the required stack space.

Comment: Enabling tail-call optimization would also prevent the program from crashing, because Nathan's comment doesn't apply to tail recursion.

Comment: With 5000000, the program will put a lot of frames on the stack. (Worse case scenario, 5000000 frames.)  Since each frame takes up some space (varies by platform, but let's say 128 bytes minimum), your program will need about 611 MB of stack space.  Many platforms default to 1 MB or 4 MB or 16 MB of stack space.  You'd need to increase your stack size accordingly.  How to do so varies by platform and/or compiler.

Comment: @Eljay there are two nested recursions, so worst case is actually `5000000^2` frames.

Comment: Also note, the way `count_primes` uses recursion will thwart tail-call optimization.

Comment: I don't know if your assignment had recursion as a requirement; however, recursion is a poor choice for this particular problem.

Comment: What you are experiencing is commonly called a _stack overflow_.

Comment: To increase the limit of recursions, you should not recurse for even numbers (except 2).  All primes after 2 are odd.  That's about a 50% savings on resources.

Comment: To make it tail recursive `count_primes` might need an additional (`acc` as accumulator) parameter and in return, only call the `count_primes(start + 1, end, is_prime(start))`. That way, it doesn't have to do anything after the call (and thus can be tail recursive).

Comment: @Spencer Why do you think recursion is wrong here? I've provided below a tail recursive (sub-optimal) solution. I expect (as per standard) it to be tail-recursive.

Comment: @lorro  You're relying on a particular type of optimization here, in order to implement an algorithm that is by its very nature far from optimal.

Comment: My rule: *the maximum recursion level for a recursive function shall be **O(log n)***. Having a **O(n)** level like this implementation is asking for trouble: it will quickly crash with (not so) big `n`. And this type of recursive function can be very easily converted to a loop, that is easier to understand, easier to debug, safer and faster.

Comment: @Spencer yes, it's implementation-defined - but the major compilers (vscpp, gcc, icc, clang) support it to my knowledge for quite some time. As for non-optimality, OP asked for this particular way of calculating count of primes. For this particular way, with TCO, the solution is as good as can be (if, of course, we implement the no-even-primes-above-2) I think, cmiiw.

Answer (score 0):

It is nice that you try to solve it in a functional manner. There are two points where you can improve it:

- make it tail recursive: do not do anything to the result of the recursing call before returning it, i.e., all return statements in `count_primes()` should look like `return count_primes(...);`. To achieve this, you might need to introduce additional accumulator parameter(s), in this case just an `acc`.
- optimize a bit: note that `is_prime()` returns a boolean, so you can add it to the accumulator, no need for if-statement. Set `num`'s initial value in `is_prime()` to `sqrt(num)`. Also, compile with `-O3` and newer standards (C++20 possibly).

The code that works for 10, 5000000 on my machine looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
bool is_prime(int num , int cnt = -1){
    if(cnt == -1)
        cnt = sqrt(num);

    if(num <= 1)
        return false;

    if(cnt == 1)
        return true;

    if(num % cnt == 0)
        return false;

    return is_prime(num , cnt-1);
}
 
int count_primes(int start , int end, int acc = 0){
    if(start>end)
        return acc;
    return count_primes(start+1 , end, acc + is_prime(start));
}

int main()
{
    cout<<count_primes(10 , 5000000);
 
    return 0;
}
```